# Using multiple Ui's and Ui classes in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qmainwindow, qt-signals

I have a simple program and I cannot remember how to use multiple Ui form classes in the same program. I have the `MainWindow` class, which has a button, which opens the `Browser` class. The classes are pretty much their defaults, and this is what I use to open the `Browser` class ui:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    this->hide();
    Browser browser;
    browser.show();
}
```

The constructor in `Browser` is simple `ui->setupUi(this)`.

What happens is the `Browser` window opens and then closes immediately.

Comment: Please do not use `this->` excessively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create the Browser on the heap, i.e.:

```
Browser* browser=new Browser(this);
browser->show();
```

because I assume it is not modal.

Comment: I suppose it's sorta modal, as it gets rid of the other window, but I think it's really non-modal, as if the other window were there, it would still be accessible. Is this a correct understanding of modality in Qt?

Comment: @JVE999 and user2672165: Fwiw, the answer is incorrect at "you need to"... It is an option, but there is more than just this one option. Also, clarification questions are better suited in comments, so it is better to put such things in there, or write a statement into your answer that "provided ...", etc.

Comment: True, this was specifically what solved the problem. Also, I'm a pointer wizard :) I like pointers. I can't mark two as correct, unfortunately, so I gave both a +1

Comment: @JVE999: I am not saying which answer to select, I am just claiming that this answer will be at the top as of now by your selection, and it is incorrect claiming that this is the only option. People will usually read the selected at the top, and they will get taught that this is the only way.

Comment: Adjusted the vocabulary. I am not a native speaker, but it was understood anyway.

Comment: Still wrong grammar ... ;) I would use "You could...".

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are allocating the browser object on the stack, and then it immediately gets destroyed at the end of the function.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    hide();
    Browser browser; // <--- constructed
    browser.show();
}                    // <--- destructed
```

You have two options to fix it:

- Make it a heap object with "this" as the parent. This will make sure that the object is not destroyed at the end of your function, but will not leak either because when the parent gets destroyed, the children get automatically destroyed, too, with the Qt parent/child hierarchy.

  ```
  void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
  {
      hide();
      Browser *browser = new Browser(this);
      browser->show();
  }
  ```
- Make it as a class member. This will outlive the scope of the function, so it will be fine.

  ```
  void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
  {
      hide();
      m_browser.show();
  }
  ```